# Confused about Saiku Analytics javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, customization, analytics, saiku

I am trying to customize the user interface of the Saiku Analytics 3.11 Pentaho plugin. Everything was fine until I needed to customize the greeting page, the one that you click the "Create a new query" button. I could not find the HTML page equivalent of the page, so I searched the entire Pentaho directory for a paragraph of text of the greeting page and found the `saiku.min.js` file, from which the paragraph was coming from.

Now, I have no idea what is happening is this file. Here's the function from where the paragraph I've found is coming:

```
function(){var a=$("\x3cdiv\x3e \x3cdiv id\x3d'splash'\x3e \x3cnav\x3e \x3cul\x3e \x3cli class\x3d'active'\x3e\x3ca class\x3d'welcome head' href\x3d'#'\x3eWelcome\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/li\x3e \x3cli\x3e\x3ca class\x3d'features head' href\x3d'#'\x3eFeatures\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/li\x3e \x3cli\x3e\x3ca class\x3d'help head' href\x3d'#'\x3eGet Help\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/li\x3e \x3cli class\x3d'enterprisetoggle enterprise'\x3e\x3ca class\x3d'enterprise head' href\x3d'#'\x3eEnterprise\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/li\x3e \x3c/ul\x3e \x3ch2\x3eExplore Data. Visualise. Act.\x3c/h2\x3e \x3c/nav\x3e \x3csection class\x3d'stabs'\x3e \x3csection style\x3d'margin-top:50px;min-height:700px;' id\x3d'welcome'\x3e \x3cdiv style\x3d'width:50%;float:left;'\x3e \x3ch1 class\x3d'saikulogo'\x3eSaiku\x3c/h1\x3e \x3cp\x3eSaiku has the power to change the way you think about your business and make decisions.   Saiku provides powerful, web based analytics for everyone in your organisation. Quickly and easily analyse data from any data  source to discover what is really happening inside and outside your organisation. \x3ci class\x3d'icon icon-remove' style\x3d'height: 100px;'\x3e\x3c/i\x3e  \x3c/p\x3e \x3ch2\x3e
```

I have no knowledge in JavaScript so this confused me a lot. Is this calling a external HTML file or generating it via JS? What is this `\x3` stuff? I only need to delete whatever is generating this page and preserve only the "Create a new query" button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

saiku.min.js is just the [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) file. Here (https://github.com/OSBI/saiku/tree/development/saiku-ui) you have the all UI of Saiku, so you can edit and after replace your UI of saiku in pentaho with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

In saiku, they are rendering Home page as encoded string of HTML stored in **saiku.min.js**

You can uglify the saiku.min.js and keep the HTML content for that button that you want to show on home screen of Saiku

Hope this would help to solve your problem.